# Display textarea when InOut radio is checked

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I need to display a textarea when my input radio is checked but my div does not appears. I need to display a textarea when my input radio is checked but my div does not appears.

```
<script>
    $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();
    $("input:radio[name='choixContenuPP']").change(function(){  
        if(this.value == 'OContenuPP' && this.checked){
            $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").show();
        }else{
            $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();
        }
    });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-7 control-label">Le contenu du poste de travail a-t-il évolué depuis le dernier entretien professionnel ?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="choixContenuPP" id="OContenuPP" value="OContenuPP"> Oui
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="choixContenuPP" id="NContenuPP" value="OContenuPP"> Non
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="divTAchoixContenuPP" style="display:none;">
    <label for="TAchoixContenuPP" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Si oui, préciser les principaux changements </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="TAchoixContenuPP" id="TAchoixContenuPP" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `display:none` from div

Comment: done, but my textarea is displayed everytime now

Comment: open the console and check is there any error .

Comment: Can you provide me fiddle with your code?

Comment: In `<div class="col-sm-4">` you have to set `display:none` when you input box is checked then you have to do `display:block`

Comment: `this.value == 'OContenuPP' && this.checked` condition will always true.
Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jo78dqbL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for both your radio options is 'OContenuPP', so the if clause

```
if(this.value == 'OContenuPP' && this.checked){
```

will always be true, hence the div does not disappear.

I fixed your code for you: https://jsfiddle.net/gemto31j/

All I did was change the value of the second radio option to

value="**N**ContenuPP"

Good luck!

Comment: I assumed the last }) belonged to your document.ready() function, so I figured that wasn't your mistake (like someone below suggested). The working examples posted by Mihail and GibboK still don't (didn't, GibboK updated his now) hide the div, which I presumed was your main problem (since showing the div worked in your example as well). Zakaria posted exactly the same solution as I did. I was interested to find your '&& this.checked', I didn't know that was necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Remove last `});`. It is not needed.

```
$("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();

$("input:radio[name='choixContenuPP']").change(function(){  

  if(this.value == 'OContenuPP' && this.checked){
    $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").show();
  }else{
    $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();
  }

});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rwpq7Lfu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please note you are using using the same value in the both radio.

Use the following JS:
https://jsfiddle.net/5v72Ldqq/10/

```
 // make sure your dom is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide your text box when page load
  $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();
  // select your radio buttons
  $("input[name=choixContenuPP]:radio").change(function() {
    // if the value is checked
    if (this.checked) {
      // show textarea
      $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").show();
    } else {
      // hidetextarea
      $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You have the same `value` in the both inputs `value='OContenuPP'`.

**Solution**

Change the `value` of the second `input` to `NContenuPP` :

```
<input type="radio" name="choixContenuPP" id="NContenuPP" value="NContenuPP">
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Working Snippet

```js
$("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();

$("input:radio[name='choixContenuPP']").change(function(){
  if(this.value == 'OContenuPP' && this.checked){
    $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").show();
  }else{
    $("#divTAchoixContenuPP").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="col-sm-7 control-label">Le contenu du poste de travail a-t-il évolué depuis le dernier entretien professionnel ?</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="choixContenuPP" id="OContenuPP" value="OContenuPP" /> Oui
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="choixContenuPP" id="NContenuPP" value="NContenuPP" /> Non
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="divTAchoixContenuPP">
  <label for="TAchoixContenuPP" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Si oui, préciser les principaux changements </label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="TAchoixContenuPP" id="TAchoixContenuPP" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```